# Как создать простейший ивент?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-keyboard

Столкнулся с проблемой проверки нажатия кнопок (модуль keyboard) всё до чего я дошёл - гонять в цикле `isbuttonpressed` (так же была идея гонять в само вызывающейся функции, но память не вечная и идея самоустранилась), как можно сделать ивент который просто будет ждать? (желательно ивент на несколько кнопок)

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте функцию `add_hotkey`

Пример:

```
import keyboard

keyboard.add_hotkey('Ctrl + Shift + 1', lambda: print('GO!'))
keyboard.wait()
```

Если никаких действие не нужно выполнять и ждать, тогда можно просто в `wait` указывать:

```
import keyboard

keyboard.wait('Ctrl + Shift + 1')

print('GO!')
```

Comment: Спасибо, первый способ - то что нужно

Comment: @Kripl, пожалуйста :)